# How to setup endpoints for particular SSL certificates in ASP.NET Core?

Tags: asp.net-core, ssl, https, tls1.2

The situation scenario:

I have 3 endpoints ( E1,E2,E3 ).I also have 3 certificates (C1,C2,C3)
I also need to provide behavior that E1 requires C1, E2 requires  C2, E3 requires  C3.

If for example API X want data from my E1 ( in for example myAPI ) there will be requirement for C1 certificate. How to configure that?

Also next question, what is difference between configuring SSL in IIS server and in ASP.NET Core app?

Comment: What does 3 endpoints mean? Is it three servers? Or an application that deploys 3 second-level domain names?

Comment: @Jason I mean that I have one API, on one server, and for example in one controller I have E1,E2,E3 (three different endpoints). Every of them should need another certificate. My question is how to do it.

Comment: You currently have only one project, now deployed on one server. Assuming that the main domain name of the site is `test.com`, you are now bound to `e1.test.com`, `e2.test.com`, `e3.test.com`. So you want to bind three certificates to this webapp, right?

Comment: Is my understanding correct? From your original post content and comment, I think the description is still not clear enough, if possible, it is better to provide pictures and descriptions.